# Install code analysis in Vistual Studio 2008 Team System 2008 SP1 without installation media?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, code-analysis

Can I install code analysis in VSTS2008 SP1 without the original installation media?  Is there a seperate package I can download to activate it?  I've installed FxCop 1.36 but that didn't automatically activate the tabs on project properties.

I checked if code analysis was installed by going to Add/Remove Programes, selecting Team System from the list and choosing Uninstall/Change.  I can then see in the treeview that the code analysis checkbox is not checked.  I don't have a copy of the installation media with me and I want to try to get around this rather than waiting several days to get the disks.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no good way to do this.  I've reinstalled Visual Studio and made sure it was right from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the trial iSO, mount or burn that and then initiate the install through add / remove programs and specify the trial media as a source if possible.  The trial media is probably the same as retail for the purposes of copying files

I have never tried this, but similar stratergies have worked with other software (ie. adding features to Windows)

Comment: Innovative! I could give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not already installed? I didn't have to specify this when I did a vanilla install of Vistual Studio Team System 2008

Unless you have a project open, the options don't appear under the 'Analyze' menu option.